# How to know which returned data belong to which entity in solr/solrj?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have defined many entities in `solr`. For example,

```
<document name="content">
    <entity name="post" query="SELECT * FROM post">
            // field mappings
        </entity>
        <entity name="category" query="select * from category " >
           // field mappings    
        </entity>
</document>
```

I'm using `solrj` to perform searching tasks. When searching a keyword, for instance `'facebook'`, both `post` and `category` containing the keyword '`facebook`' so solr returns data of `post` and `category`. But how can I know which data belong to `post` and which ones belong to `category` entity?
(I use solr 4.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better keep a common field (say "entity") in both type of Solr doc. Store the entity name for each one. When you query, by the entity value, you'll know the result belongs to which entity.

E.g For entity "post" keep `entity:post`